# pass a value to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file in python and writing into another file. While writing I am passing some parameters to the output file which I declared below.

```
test = abc  -  The value of test is abc.

with open("abc.txt","r") as file:
    with open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in file:
            line = line.split("|")
            new_line = ('{test}|{0}|{1}|{2}\n'.format(line[0],line[1],line[2])
            outfile.write(new_line)
```

Input is

```
a|b|c
q|w|e
```

The value of parameter is not passing to the output file. I am getting the output as

```
test|a|b|c
test|q|w|e
```

expected output is

```
abc|a|b|c
abc|q|w|e
```

Comment: You use the named parameter syntax (`'{parameter}'`) but you never pass a kwarg named `parameter` in your call to `format()`.

Comment: Where you have: `parameter = abc`, what is `abc`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. The code shown *cannot* produce the shown output – it will fail with a ``KeyError: 'test'``. Take note that if you want to go from ``a|b|c``, there is no need to split the line – ``f"{test}|{line}"`` should be enough.

Comment: Where you have: `test = abc`, what is `abc`?

Comment: please try now. I have updated the code.

Comment: Test is a variable and it has value abc. I was to add that variable value to the output file.

Comment: Yes, your program quite clearly states that `test = abc`, but what value does `abc` have?

Comment: @SparkUser You meant to write `test = "abc"` so `abc` a literal string, not a variable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895835/format-strings-and-named-arguments-in-python/17895844

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a variable name in a format string doesn't get replaced with the variable's value. It needs to reference a named parameter.

```
new_line = ('{test}|{0}|{1}|{2}\n'.format(line[0],line[1],line[2], test = test)
```